# How to use MultipleOutputs format to generate custom file name with generating other files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, multipleoutputs

I am writing Orc files using MultipleOutputs format to create a custom file name. I am setting the Driver as below

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "MyPrefix", OrcNewOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Writable.class);
```

In Reducer as below

setup:

```
_multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Writable>(context);
```

Reduce method:

```
_multipleOutputs.write("MyPrefix", NullWritable.get(), row);
```

cleanup method:

```
_multipleOutputs.close();
```

Though for files having data it generates with prefix "MyPrefix", but is also generating part-00000 file having no record.

Please let me know how can I stop reducer generating this empty file with name part-00000.

Comment: This is because `MultipleOutputs` acts as a "byside" output channel. If I recall correctly, you can  disable "normal" output channel by setting output format to `NullOutputFormat`.